# Trying to set logstash conf file in docker-compose.yml on Mac OS

Tags: macos, docker, docker-compose, logstash, logstash-configuration

Here is what I have specified in my yml for the logstash. I've tried multiple variations of quotes, no quotes, etc:

```
      volumes:
              - "./logstash:/etc/logstash/conf:ro"
      command:
              - "logstash -f /etc/logstash/conf/simplels.conf"
```

And simplels.conf contains this:

```
        input {
           stdin{}
        }
    
        output {
          elasticsearch {
            hosts => ["localhost:9200"]
          }
          stdout{}
        }
```

Overall file structure is this, I'm running docker-compose up from the docker folder and getting Exit 1 on the Logstash container due to my 'command' parameter:

```
/docker:
  docker-compose.yml
  /logstash
    simplels.conf
```

Comment: What happens if you directly mount the simplels.conf file instead of just the path? Also, if you temporarily remove the command and let the container fire up, are you able to confirm the simplels.conf is there (in the container)?

Comment: Same result if I directly mount the simplels.conf file. I can verify the directory mounts via docker inspect.
  

docker logs command gives this:   
  

/usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint: line 14: /usr/share/logstash/logstash -f ./etc/logstash/conf/simplels.conf: No such file or directory